# Laravel 5.8: How to show a column information of a pivot table in Many To Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have a Many To Many relationship between User Model & Wallet Model:

**Wallet.php**:

```
public function users() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'user_wallet','user_id','wallet_id');
}
```

And **User.php**:

```
public function wallets() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Wallet::class,'user_wallet','user_id','wallet_id');
}
```

And the `pivot table` of this relationship goes like this:

[image]

So I can properly show Wallet name at the Blade:

```
@forelse($user->wallets as $wallet)
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ $wallet->name }}
        </td>
        <td>
            {{ $wallet->balance }}
        </td>
    </tr>
@empty
    <td colspan="5" class="text-center">
        No wallet exist
    </td>
@endforelse
```

But the wallet balance data does not appear (because it's in the pivot table and not the `wallets` table).

So how to show this custom column in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `withPivot` and mention additional column name

```
public function wallets()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Wallet::class,'user_wallet','user_id','wallet_id')->withPivot('balance');
}
```

then in view

```
  <td>{{ $wallet->pivot->balance }}</td>
```